# swift 3 google maps - how to update marker on the map

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, xcode8

i am using google maps

this is my code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func pressed(_ sender: Any) {

    //self.myMapView.marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: +31.75097956, longitude: +35.23694378)

}




@IBOutlet weak var myMapView: GMSMapView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: +31.75097946, longitude: +35.23694368, zoom: 17.0)
    self.myMapView.mapType =  .terrain
    self.myMapView.camera = camera
    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: +31.75097946, longitude: +35.23694368)
    marker.title = "some text"
    marker.map = self.myMapView
    marker.opacity = 1.0

}
```

There is a UIView that into it loads the map. There is also a button.
When pressing a button, I want to update location of marker.

thanks

Comment: Do you want update the marker location of which you added on the `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: yes. that is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `marker` as a class variable. And the button click function add the following code

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var myMapView: GMSMapView!
var marker: GMSMarker!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: +31.75097946, longitude: +35.23694368, zoom: 17.0)
    self.myMapView.mapType =  .terrain
    self.myMapView.camera = camera
    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: +31.75097946, longitude: +35.23694368)
    marker.title = "some text"
    marker.map = self.myMapView
    marker.opacity = 1.0

}

@IBAction func pressed(_ sender: Any) {

    //New location coordinate 
     marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -1.75097946, longitude: +15.23694368)

     let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: marker.position, zoom: 17.0)
     mapView.camera = camera

}
}
```